# Read excel file in spfx pnp js

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, excel, pnpjs

I want to read an excel file which is stored in SharePoint library in PNP JS. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Mian code:

```
 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';  



sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/SPCapabilityTeam/Documents/ss.xlsx").getBuffer().then((buffer: ArrayBuffer) => {  
                    var workbook = XLSX.read(buffer, {  
                        type: "buffer"  
                    });  
                    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];  
                    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];  
                    var headers = {};  
                    var data = [];  
                    let z: any;  
                    for (z in worksheet) {  
                        if (z[0] === '!') continue;  
                        var tt = 0;  
                        for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {  
                            if (!isNaN(z[i])) {  
                                tt = i;  
                                break;  
                            }  
                        }  
                        var col = z.substring(0, tt);  
                        var row = parseInt(z.substring(tt));  
                        var value = worksheet[z].v;  
                        //store header names  
                        if (row == 1 && value) {  
                            headers[col] = value;  
                            continue;  
                        }  
                        if (!data[row]) data[row] = {};  
                        data[row][headers[col]] = value;  
                    }  
                    console.log(data)  
                });
```

Reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/reading-sharepoint-document-library-excel-file-using-spfx-and-pnpjs